# OpenCV 3.0 include tracker

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to use a tracker, described on the [OpenCV 3.0 documentation site](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/tracking/doc/tracker_algorithms.html). In OpenCV 2.x, it was necessary to recompile OpenCV including the contrib library. But as it is in the OpenCV 3 documentation, I guess that I do not have to recompile it anymore, right? But what do I have to #include in C++?

I'm trying to do this for quit a while and do not find any solution. Thank you!

**EDIT**
Thank you! The recompiling-process worked for me without any errors. I got still several errors: He does not find 'opencv_highgui300d.dll', 'opencv_imgcodecs300d.dll'and 'opencv_core300d.dll'.

I fixed this, because I had to change the 'Path' system variable to

`...\cmake-output\vc12\x86\install\x86\vc12\bin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the tracking module is still in the "contrib" module.

You have to re-compile OpenCV 3.0 using the contrib section that you may download from [this github repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). When you compile OpenCV using CMake you have to specify the **OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH** atribute as being the location where you have extracted the module.

If you have any issues, just let me know :)

**[EDIT]**

1. Download **OpenCV** from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) and OpenCV_Contrib module from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). Unzip them and place them in the same directory (I have put mine in D:/OPENCV-BUILD)/
2. Open CMake and set the source code path to D:/OPENCV-BUILD/opencv-master
3. Set the "Where to build the binaries" path to D:/OPENCV-BUILD/cmake-output/vc12/x86. Here, **vc12** is the platform toolset used by VS2013 and **x86** is the platform target (you may build it for x64 also)
4. Press the configure button and select your generator (a.k.a the compiler you'd like to use). Select **Visual Studio 12 2013** (for **x86** build) or **Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64** (for **x64** build).
5. Wait until it's done configuring. A bunch of red lines will appear, dont't worry it's all good :)
6. Search for the following lines and uncheck them:

**WITH_CUDA** -> this will disable support for GPU accelerated algorithms using CUDA technology. You can build the library with CUDA support also, but it's a bit more complicated and it takes much longer. If you don't need it, un-check it :)

**BUILD_DOCS**, **BUILD_PERF_TESTS**, **BUILD_TESTS**. These are just some tests of the modules of the library (that I have never ever used)... Again, if you don't need them, un-check them :)

**Everything related to Matlab** (if you have these options). I have Matlab installed and CMake wanted to create some Matlab bindings for OpenCV. I had some issues at compiling the library with these options, so I deleted them (see the image below)

[image]

7. Search for "extra" and in the **OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH** set the path to your "modules" folder from the contrib module (mine is `D:/OPENCV-BUILD/opencv_contrib-master/modules`)

[image]

8. Now click again on the "Configure" button. Wait until it says "Configuring done", and after that press on the "Generate" button. We're done with CMake!
9. In the output folder you have selected (`D:\OPENCV-BUILD\cmake-output\vc12\x86`) you'll find `OpenCV.sln`. Open it using VS2013.
10. In Visual Studio, select the configuration you'd like to build (I recommend you to build both for Debug and Release). Let's say you select 'Debug' first. Now right click on the solution and select "Build Solution". Wait until it's done.
11. In the 'CMakeTargets' folder you'll find a project named INSTALL. Right click on it and select 'Project Only -> Build Only INSTALL'). This creates a new folder named install and copies the result of the build there (libs, dlls, include files, etc.).

[image]

12. Repeat steps 10 and 11 for the 'Release' configuration.
13. After these steps, you'll have the files you need in your install folder (mine is `D:\OPENCV-BUILD\cmake-output\vc12\x86\install`)

Comment: Thank you :)! So I tried this and compiled it for my Visual Studio Version to a new folder, called 'release'. This worked fine without any errors. But what do I have to do then? I read that I have to compile the OpenCV.sln file in my release folder, is that right? Or can I just add the new release folder to the directory path in VS? Thank you again, you are a great help for me! :)

Comment: After you have done the set-up in CMake, the code was 'generated', not 'compiled'. You have to open the OpenCV.sln file and compile it for the desired platform and mode (ex. x86, Release or x64 Debug, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is it right to set the build directory in CMake to a new folder in the OpenCV folder or should I set the build directory to the build folder that already exists in OpenCV?

Comment: Set the build directory in CMake anywhere you want. That's the folder where CMake will generate the visual studio solution for you. What version of Visual Studio are you using? Maybe I could take some screenshots of the process for you...

Comment: I'm using VS 2013. Screenshots would be perfect! But as I am new to VS, I do also not know how to exactly include the lib. I know roughly that I have to set the include and library path at the property sheet and add something at the linker (adding the name of some .lib files) but I am not sure about these steps.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the steps required to build OpenCV 3.0 with the contrib modules. If you need any help including the libraries in your app let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The following link points to a very clear and nice explanation of how to install OpenCV properly and not have any problems with compilation and provided libraries.

This is the proper way to get a clean installation on Windows 7:

https://coderwall.com/p/wgaiwa/setup-opencv-with-vs2012-on-win7-64bit?p=1&q=author%3AVentsy

Hope it helps